# RecyclerView Adapter refreshes when I sent message for first time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build a chat app. I am using the Recycler Adapter. The issue I am facing is that whenever I enter the text and hit send for the first time, The Activity/Recyler Adapter gets refreshed and the sent text comes up in a refreshed activity, rather than showing up on the last line of the current view.

There are no errors and I am not sure where to debug.

[image]

Here are the screenshots of the app on what is happening.

Below is the first screen where I can see all the past messages when I come to the screen for first time.

[image]

Below is the screenshot where I type something. Ideally this should take scrolltoposition and show this message at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Below is the third screenshot, which shows what is happening. The sent message shows up in a new activity/recyclerview adapter.

[image]

So I am not getting any errors which I can figure out what is happening except the one saying "This" is not available.

Please provide ideas/suggestions to debug.

Here is the code for the Chat Activity.

```
public class Askquest extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "Askquest";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter PChatAdapter;
    private List<SendQues> messages;
    private int userID;
    private ImageView img_send;
    private EditText et_message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_askquest);

    PChatAdapter = new PChatAdapter(messages, Askquest.this);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_chat);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(PChatAdapter);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    messages = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    SharedPreferences msharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();

    String messageBy = msharedprefs.getString("username", null);
    int user_id = 22;
    Log.i("TAG", ""+messageBy);
    int channel_id = 4;

    ReqResp reqResp = new ReqResp(user_id, channel_id, messageBy);
    reqResp.setChannelId(channel_id);
    reqResp.setUserId(user_id);
    reqResp.setUsername(messageBy);

    fetchMessages(reqResp);
    img_send = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_send);
    et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    img_send.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @OnClick({R.id.img_send})
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == img_send)
        {
            // get msg from edit text
            String msg = et_message.getText().toString();
            if (et_message.getText().toString().isEmpty()) return;
            SendQues message = new SendQues();
            SharedPreferences msharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();
            String message_by = msharedprefs.getString("username", null);
            int user_id = 23;
            int channel_id = 4;
            message.setUserId(user_id);
            message.setMessageBy(message_by);
            message.setMessageAt(String.valueOf(getTimeStamp()));
            message.setMessageBody(msg);
            message.setId(channel_id);
            //messages.add(message);
            et_message.setText("");
            sendMessage(message);
            //PChatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);
            //recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
        }
    }

    private void fetchMessages(final ReqResp reqResp)
    {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<SendQues>> call = apiService.aresponse(reqResp);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SendQues>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SendQues>> call, Response<List<SendQues>> response) {
                List<SendQues> sendQues = response.body();
                PChatAdapter PChatAdapter = new PChatAdapter(sendQues, Askquest.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(PChatAdapter);
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(sendQues.size()-1);
                Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Fetching Responses Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SendQues>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Fetching Responses Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(final SendQues messageP){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<pQuestionResp> call = apiService.aquestion(messageP);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<pQuestionResp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<pQuestionResp> call, Response<pQuestionResp> response) {
                pQuestionResp message = response.body();
                if (message != null && message.getQStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                    messages.add(messageP);
                    PChatAdapter = new PChatAdapter(messages, Askquest.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(PChatAdapter);
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
                    Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "messages got null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<pQuestionResp> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Error Sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public static String getTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return format.format(new Date());
    }
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Adapter

```
    public class PChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
private List<SendQues> messages;
private Context context;

public PChatAdapter(List<SendQues> messages, Context context) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.context = context;
    Log.i("TAG", "PChatAdapter");
}


@Override
//public PChatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.i("TAG", "onCreateViewHolder");
    View itemView;

    if (viewType == MessageType.SENT_TEXT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ViewType Defined as Self");

        return new SentMessageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent,parent,false));
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "ViewType Defined as Not Self");

        return new RecvdMessageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent,false));
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    Log.i(TAG, "position");
    SendQues sendQues = messages.get(position);

    Log.i(TAG,"" +messages.get(position));
    if (type == MessageType.SENT_TEXT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "*****************Printing Sent Message ***************************");

        SentMessageHolder sentMessageHolder = (SentMessageHolder) holder;
        sentMessageHolder.messageAt.setText(sendQues.getMessageAt());
        sentMessageHolder.messageBody.setText(sendQues.getMessageBody());

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "*****************Printing Received Message ***************************");

        RecvdMessageHolder recvdMessageHolder = (RecvdMessageHolder) holder;
        recvdMessageHolder.messageAt.setText(sendQues.getMessageAt());
        recvdMessageHolder.messageBody.setText(sendQues.getMessageBody());
        recvdMessageHolder.messageBy.setText(sendQues.getMessageBy());
    }
}

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getitemviewtype");
    SendQues sendQues = messages.get(position);

    SharedPreferences msharedprefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedprefdata",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();

    String msgsender = msharedprefs.getString("username", "kkk");

    Log.i("TAG", ""+msgsender);
    if (sendQues.getMessageBy().equalsIgnoreCase(msgsender)) {
        return MessageType.SENT_TEXT;
    }
    else
        return MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    Log.i(TAG, "getitemcount");

    if (messages != null) {
        return messages.size();

    } else return 0;
}

class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView messageBody;
    public TextView messageAt;
    public TextView messageBy;

    public SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBody);
        messageAt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageAt);
        messageBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBy);
    }
}

class RecvdMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView messageBody;
    public TextView messageAt;
    public TextView messageBy;

    public RecvdMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBody);
        messageAt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageAt);
        messageBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBy);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: add some code snippets here. Specially the part where you hit send button and what happens after that.

Comment: do you want to show the message from button of the list?

Comment: yes. Message should ideally show up at the bottom of the list

Comment: @JMeterDude Please have a look if in your Send button click event you are clearing the arraylist that saves the messages by calling the `clear()` method or assigning a `new ArrayList()` to the same variable.

Comment: Please share the code which is relevant with the problem.

Comment: @JMeterDude your previous messages get clear or they are remaining on the list? as in your last screenshot, it seems previous messages gets clear.

Comment: I dont think the previous messages are getting cleared. I see it as the previous messages view is getting refreshed and a new Recyclerview is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Askquest extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final String TAG = "Askquest";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PChatAdapter adapter;//Changed here
private List<SendQues> messages;
private int userID;
private ImageView img_send;
private EditText et_message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_askquest);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_chat);

messages = new ArrayList<>();//Changed here
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));//updated
adapter= new PChatAdapter(messages, Askquest.this);//Changed here
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

SharedPreferences msharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();

String messageBy = msharedprefs.getString("username", null);
int user_id = 22;
Log.i("TAG", ""+messageBy);
int channel_id = 4;

ReqResp reqResp = new ReqResp(user_id, channel_id, messageBy);
reqResp.setChannelId(channel_id);
reqResp.setUserId(user_id);
reqResp.setUsername(messageBy);

fetchMessages(reqResp);
img_send = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_send);
et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
img_send.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@OnClick({R.id.img_send})
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == img_send)
    {
        // get msg from edit text
        String msg = et_message.getText().toString();
        if (et_message.getText().toString().isEmpty()) return;
        SendQues message = new SendQues();
        SharedPreferences msharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = msharedprefs.edit();
        String message_by = msharedprefs.getString("username", null);
        int user_id = 23;
        int channel_id = 4;
        message.setUserId(user_id);
        message.setMessageBy(message_by);
        message.setMessageAt(String.valueOf(getTimeStamp()));
        message.setMessageBody(msg);
        message.setId(channel_id);
        //messages.add(message);
        et_message.setText("");
        sendMessage(message);
        //PChatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);
        //recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
    }
}

private void fetchMessages(final ReqResp reqResp)
{

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<List<SendQues>> call = apiService.aresponse(reqResp);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SendQues>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SendQues>> call, Response<List<SendQues>> response) {
            List<SendQues> sendQues = response.body();
            messages.addAll(sendQues);//Changed here
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();//Changed here
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
            Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Fetching Responses Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SendQues>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Fetching Responses Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage(final SendQues messageP){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<pQuestionResp> call = apiService.aquestion(messageP);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<pQuestionResp>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<pQuestionResp> call, Response<pQuestionResp> response) {
            pQuestionResp message = response.body();
            if (message != null && message.getQStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
            messages.add(messageP);//Changed here
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);//Changed here
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
            Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Fetching Responses Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "messages got null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<pQuestionResp> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Askquest.this, "Error Sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
    public static String getTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return format.format(new Date());
    }
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
    }
}
```

> Please have a look i have modified some code where marked as //Changed here

Don't do this everytime

```
 PChatAdapter pChatAdapter = new PChatAdapter(sendQues, Askquest.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(PChatAdapter);
```

instead use `pChatAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`or any of notify method.

Comment: check now i have update new LinearLayoutManager(this)

Comment: Working. Awesome. Thank you. I kind of guessed that could be an issue but didnt know how to solve. Thank you. For the earlier error I believe I put the layout manager before initializing the layout ID and thats why the error. I corrected and now this works like a smooth cake

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
  layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
  layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
  layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: Nope. Didnt work. The RecyclerView still gets refreshed and I see the screen where the latest message I sent comes up on a new screen.